# Indicator of "accepted answer" is not displayed in /questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When at http://ell.stackexchange.com, the listing shows the green circle indicator for accepted answers.
[image]

However, when I go to https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions and check the same question, the indicator is gone.
[image]

I checked a couple of other SE sites. Seasoned Advice SE seem to be this way, but another (JL SE) displays the indicator in both lists.

Is there some logic here that I am missing?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me... Let me look into passing it along to those who can mend it!

Comment: @WendiKidd Is there any chance we could poke the powers that be one more time and remind them that this is broken?

Comment: @colleen absolutely--I'll take care of that now :)

Answer (score 4):

This issue is now fixed. Thanks for letting us know!

Comment: What a quick response; thank you!

Comment: Thanks. You might also check Seasoned Advice SE that has the same problem. For reference I checked this question in both lists. [What's the difference between hollandaise, mayonnaise, and aïoli?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/71828/whats-the-difference-between-hollandaise-mayonnaise-and-a%c3%afoli)